# Multiple JFrames, or JDialogs

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jdialog

From a variety of resources (this website, a book, a friend) I have managed to make a `JFrame`(JFrame1) that responds to a button. It makes another `JFrame` (JFrame2), and changes the `JFrame.setVisible()` to `false`.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when a declared Back button is pressed, it closes `JFrame2` and sets `JFrame1` visibility to `true`. That's all fine, but when I do `JFrame2.setVisiblity(false)`, `JFrame2` is still visible. I've tried `dispose()`; but that doesn't work either.

I'm also wondering, since I've read on stackoverflow, that creating multiple `JFrames` is bad programming. So should I use `JDialogs` instead?

I am trying to display a bunch of information, and allow you to interact with the GUI to navigate around the information. The information would be arranged by alphabetical order.

Also, I'm not sure how to post code on here, so if you need to see what I currently have, just tell me how to post code :D

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Paste the code, as you would do normally, then select only the code  and press Ctrl+K

Comment: You should use one JFrame and zero or more JDialogs

Answer (score 2):

You are better of using a single frame, using something like `JPanels` to hold you UI components. This way you can simply switch it the panels as you need, possibly with something like `CardLyout`

By moving your UI to panels, you are also decoupling your code, giving your more flexibility and reuse potential.

### Updated with basic example

This basically uses a simple model to change out different views.  You could use a different style of model that listens to changes to the views and then makes choices on there behalf (which would generally be my preferred method), it depends on what you want to do...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CardLayoutDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CardLayoutDemo();
    }

    public CardLayoutDemo() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new MasterPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class GameModel {

        private JPanel view;
        private JPanel lastView;
        private JPanel currentView;
        private WelcomePane welcomePane;
        private GamePane gamePane;
        private SettingsPane settingsPane;

        public GameModel(JPanel view) {
            this.view = view;

            welcomePane = new WelcomePane(this);
            gamePane = new GamePane(this);
            settingsPane = new SettingsPane(this);
        }

        public void welcome() {
            lastView = currentView;
            view.removeAll();
            view.add(welcomePane);
            view.revalidate();
            view.repaint();
            currentView = welcomePane;
        }

        public void newGame() {
            lastView = currentView;
            view.removeAll();
            view.add(gamePane);
            view.revalidate();
            view.repaint();
            currentView = gamePane;
        }

        public void settings() {
            lastView = currentView;
            view.removeAll();
            view.add(settingsPane);
            view.revalidate();
            view.repaint();
            currentView = settingsPane;
        }

        public void back() {
            if (lastView != null) {
                view.removeAll();
                view.add(lastView);
                view.revalidate();
                view.repaint();
                currentView = lastView;
                lastView = null;
            }
        }

    }

    public class MasterPane extends JPanel {

        public MasterPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            GameModel model = new GameModel(this);
            model.welcome();
        }

    }

    public class WelcomePane extends JPanel {

        private GameModel model;

        public WelcomePane(GameModel gameModel) {
            this.model = gameModel;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JButton btnStart = new JButton("New Game");
            JButton btnSettings = new JButton("Settings");

            add(new JLabel("Welcome"), gbc);
            add(btnStart, gbc);
            add(btnSettings, gbc);

            btnSettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    model.settings();
                }

            });

            btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    model.newGame();
                }

            });
        }

    }

    public class SettingsPane extends JPanel {

        private GameModel model;

        public SettingsPane(GameModel gameModel) {
            this.model = gameModel;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel("Go ahead, make some changes..."), gbc);

            JButton back = new JButton("Back");
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    model.back();
                }
            });
            add(back, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        private GameModel model;

        public GamePane(GameModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("All your base are belong to us"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get rid of my first screen? I mean, my first screen is an option to find something either alphabetically or searching. Once you click that, i want to close that frame so it is only either the search bar, or the browse section.

Comment: You don't need to get rid of the frame.  Move all your UI components (and there logic) to `JPanel`s.  When the use selects something, notify a controller that will make the decision about what needs to be displayed next...